# magento 2 event for out of stock

Tags: magento2, event-observer, out-of-stock

I would like to know when a product goes out of stock by user purchase.  I think there should be an event for this.  I am not able to find it though.

Also, in general, has Magento 2 published the official list of events somewhere?  That list would be to have.

Comment: I could find the event list here.  But this is not official.  https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html#events-in-php-files